# Using internal storage to save list of integers

Tags: android, string, storage, internal

i'm trying to save a list of integers in my application by saving each integer in a new line of a file in the internal storage. 
For retreiving it I read it line by line and put every linevalue, parsed as integer, in my list of integers. 
I know a database is better for this kinda stuff, but this should work.

I am trying for quite a while now, but it never seems to work. I always get a nullpointerexception when trying to read. I logged "line", it gave the value it should have. But

saving one id, adding it as a new string:

```
private void saveToFavorites(Integer saveFav) {
            String favstr = String.valueOf(saveFav);
            BufferedWriter writer = null;
            try {
              writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("favorites", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)));
              writer.newLine();
              writer.append((favstr));
              System.out.println(" added to favs :"+ saveFav);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
              if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
        }
```

And the reading method:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("null")
    private List<Integer> readFileFromInternalStorage() {
            List<Integer> favs = null;
            BufferedReader input = null;
            try {
              input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("favorites")));
              String line;
              while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println("readFileFromInternalStorage line value: "+ line );
                 favs.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("readFileFromInternalStorage: fail" );
            } finally {
            if (input != null) {
              try {
                input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
            return favs;
        }
```

Which is in an other activity. I thought it would work but it clearly doesnt. When reading back, the logline:                System.out.println("readFileFromInternalStorage line value: "+ line );
displays that the value of line equals the LAST added id,and an empty line, and not the others too. So the line by line saving fails. Also when parsing it to an integer it fails, what is weird because it is only a number.

```
08-01 12:29:54.190: I/System.out(1540): readFileFromInternalStorage line value: 
08-01 12:29:54.190: I/System.out(1540): readFileFromInternalStorage line value: 301
```

Anyone knows what i need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Integer` is `Serializable` I sugget to serialize the entire `List`:

```
private void saveList(List<Integer> list) {
try {
            File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File filename = new File(file, "yourfilename");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(list);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private void readList()
{


    try {
                File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File filename = new File(file, "yourfilename");
                fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
                in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                List<Integer> list= (List<Integer>) in.readObject();
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

Comment: i'm trying this but i get an error: android filenotfoundexception no such file or directory, for the string i put in filename. What should i put there? write_external_memory is in my manifest, thats not it

Answer (score 1):

try this May it help you :-
    1 - String saveFav = contaains all integer this form I1+"/"I2+"/"I3;

2:- then save it into file

```
     private void saveToFavorites(String saveFav) { 
       //right here your code for write into file saveFave string
 }
```

in reading file read string and split("/").it's working for me .

Answer (score 0):

Here's some working code that will read and write ints to the phones internal memory.
You can create an array or list of ints and basically just iterate over it until all ints are saved/read to/from the memory:

Here's the code to write an int to the memory:

```
public void writePrimitiveInternalMemory(String filename, int value) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(filename, value);
        editor.commit();

    }
```

Here's code to read from the memory:

```
public int readPrimitiveInternalMemoryInteger(String filename) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getInt(filename, 0);

    }
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: With the shared prefences i had some trouble because it didn't commit when I wanted it, asked some question about that behavior before, that's why I chose for internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating the integer list...

```
List<Integer> favs = null;
```

Allocate a new arraylist..

```
List<Integer> favs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```